# Webscraping Amazon Search Pages via Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape some basic information from an amazon search page. The XPath that I've used seem to be correct, but the below code only gives me the first result for each iteration of the for loop - basically only the title of the first book x number of search results on Page 1. What am I doing wrong?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

PATH = 'ChromeDriver/chromedriver'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get('https://www.amazon.in/s?k=python+books&ref=nb_sb_noss')

sleep(2)

entries = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(@data-cel-widget, "search_result_")]')

for entry in entries:
    title = entry.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class = "a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal"]')
    
    print(title.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `entries` locator is not needed. Just loop over the results directly

```
for entry in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class = 'a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal']"):
    print(entry.text)
```

Prints:

```
Learning with Python
Machine Learning using Python
Python Crash Course, 2nd Edition: A Hands-On, Project-Based Introduction to Programming
Python: This Book Includes: Learn Python Programming + Python Coding and Programming + Python Coding. Everything you need to know to Learn Coding ... Machine Learning, Data Science and more ....
Python Programming: Using Problem Solving Approach
Automate the Boring Stuff with Python, 2nd Edition: Practical Programming for Total Beginners
...
```

**Updated solution**

Here is a way you can parse it out and assign variable names to different pieces.  Note that authors and date are actually in the same element, hence it shows both..

```
for entry in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@data-component-type='s-search-result']"):
    title = entry.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class = 'a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal']").text
    authors = entry.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='a-row a-size-base a-color-secondary']").get_attribute("innerText")
    print(title)
    print(authors)
```

prints:

```
Learning with Python
by Allen Downey , Jeffrey Elkner, et al. | 1 January 2015
Machine Learning using Python
by U Dinesh Kumar Manaranjan Pradhan | 1 January 2019
...
```

Also note in each sub-element within the loop it starts with `.//`. The dot is needed otherwise it goes back to the root each time, which is what I think the issue was that you were facing originally.

Comment: This won't work if I need to extract more than one field, right?

Comment: Correct. If you wanted to grab the authors, or date etc...you'd need to loop over a different xpath.  I thought you just wanted the book title, so that's what I went with.

Comment: @Rishi I updated the solution to be more flexible

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, the issue was the ".//".

Comment: A better way to thanks is marking the answer as accepted :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong locator for entries.
Use this: `//div[@data-component-type='s-search-result' and (not(contains(@class,'AdHolder')))]`
So that `entries = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@data-component-type='s-search-result' and (not(contains(@class,'AdHolder')))]')`
With this locator the rest will be correct.

Comment: I just get 'Learning with Python' printed 22 times.

Comment: What "this" exactly?

Comment: Apologies - what I meant was that I just get the first element in the list (entries) printed 22 times. In this case, the first element happens to be the title of the first book in the search results (i.e. 'Learning with Python'.

Answer (score 1):

how about this? I went with grabbing the text from each entry. I also replaced any new line characters with a comma for easier reading.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

PATH = 'ChromeDriver/chromedriver'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get('https://www.amazon.in/s?k=python+books&ref=nb_sb_noss')

sleep(2)

entries = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class = "a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal"]')
Prices = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class = "a-price-whole"]')

for entry in range(len(entries)):
    title = entries[entry].text
    price = Prices[entry].text
    print(title + ', ' + price)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this will work. The xpath for "entries" has much more than just the title text.

Comment: It does however solve the loop problem, i.e. it prints out all the different elements from the list created by 'entries'. Still, if I want to assign different variable names to specific parts (e.g., Title, Price, Author, etc.), all it gives me is the first entry * number of elements in the list.

Comment: isn't that a new question?